# MVC update ListboxFor with selected values from DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently working on a website in MVC, I have created a partial view with a DropDownListFor everytime a value is selected in the DropDownListFor it goes to the HttpPost and adds the value to a List. I also have a ListBoxFor that is bound to this list.

What I would like to achieve:

Everytime a new value is added to the List with the DropDownListFor it should update the ListBoxFor automatically so the selected value gets added to this Listbox. I wonder what the best way would be to achieve this.

Code:

Submit.cshtml:

```
<div class="create-ingredient">
     @Html.Partial("_CreateIngredient")
</div>
<br/>
<div class="add-ingredient">
     @Html.Partial("_AddIngredient")
</div>
<br/>
<div class="ingredient-listbox">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ingredients,"Current Ingredients")
     @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Ingredients, new MultiSelectList(Model.SelectedIngredients), new { style = "width:50%;" })
</div>
```

_AddIngredient.cshtml (Partial View):

```
@model Recepten.Models.IngredientSelectModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddIngredient", "Recipe", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "add-ingredient", HttpMethod = "Post" }))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ingredients, "Add Ingredient")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedIngredient, Model.Ingredients, "Select Ingredient", new { @onchange = "$(this).parents('form').submit();" })
}
```

AddIngredient:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddIngredient(IngredientSelectModel ing)
{
    ing.SelectedIngredients.Add(ing.SelectedIngredient);
    return PartialView(ing);
}
```

IngredientSelectModel:

```
public RecipeModel Recipe { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Ingredients { get; set; }
public int SelectedIngredient { get; set; }

public string addIngredient { get; set; }

public List<int> SelectedIngredients { get; set; }

public IngredientSelectModel()
{
    SelectedIngredients = new List<int>();
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can I ask what JavaScript has to do with this?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with javascript, but I think it's possible to make a event if there's a onclick event in the dropdownlistfor to update the listboxfor, As i'm not sure about this I have removed the tag

Comment: You need javascript to handle the change event of the dropdownlist, clone the selected option and append it to the listbox. But that will not necessarily submit back the values of `Ingredients` unless each option is selected before you submit. Its difficult to understand what your trying to achieve with this. If your wanting to select a number of ingredients for a recipe, then this is not the way to do it. You should be displaying all ingredients with an associated checkbox.

Comment: Just when you click on one item from the dropdownlist it should add it to the list & listbox and be repeatable, tried adding the onchange event to the listboxfor with no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I think you've figured, the reason the current approach isn't working is that the `IngredientSelectModel` created for and updated by the `AddIngredient` action is separate from the one used to populate the ListBox.

If Ajax and unobtrusive JQuery are set up correctly (the browser URL shouldn't change when you select an ingredient), @pinhead's answer will send the selected value to the action, but `SelectedIngredients` won't accumulate the values you select because its value isn't included in the ajax data. For that to work you need to change the multi-select to be bound to `SelectedIngredients`:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(
    model => model.SelectedIngredients,
    new MultiSelectList(Model.SelectedIngredients),
    new { style = "width:50%;" })
```

...and move it inside the form declaration so its value is posted to the action along with the new ingredient to add.

That said, I wouldn't say you're doing enough work to justify a round-trip to the server, so after making the above change you could just add the ingredient entirely on the client side like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.SelectedIngredient, 
    Model.Ingredients, 
    "Select Ingredient", 
    new { @onchange = "$('#SelectedIngredients').append('<option>' + $(this).val() + '</option>')" })
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe one solution is to move your ListBoxFor helper into your partial view so that it is updated and recreated once your action returns the partial view.

Submit.cshtml:

```
<div class="create-ingredient">
     @Html.Partial("_CreateIngredient")
</div>
<br/>
<div class="add-ingredient">
     @Html.Partial("_AddIngredient")
</div>
```

_AddIngredient.cshtml (Partial View):

```
@model Recepten.Models.IngredientSelectModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddIngredient", "Recipe", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "add-ingredient", HttpMethod = "Post" }))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ingredients, "Add Ingredient")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedIngredient, Model.Ingredients, "Select Ingredient", new { @onchange = "$(this).parents('form').submit();" })
}
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ingredients,"Current Ingredients")
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Ingredients, new MultiSelectList(Model.SelectedIngredients), new { style = "width:50%;" })
```

Comment: I have attempted this, but it did not work unfortunately

Comment: It looks like one error in your code is that your UpdateTargetId is set to a class, not an id. Also, if you haven't already installed it, you need the Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax package.

Comment: Thank you, I changed class to id="add-ingredient", no change I have the package unobtrusive ajax installed aswell, when inspecting element it is listed